# Generate Jar in netbeans 7.1

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.1

I am using netbeans 7.1 (new to it). I would like to know how to export our projects as a `.jar` file (though I have searched a lot in Internet).

Many times `./dist` folder itself is not created, even though it is created, I see only .zip files (not jar). It would be great if one can help me out in this aspect. Seems like in earlier version of netbeans, the jar would be available in `./dist` folder.

Comment: are you trying to developer Java App or Java ME App ?

Answer (score 6):

Do this before search :) (right click the project > Clean and Build)

[image]

---

When you use the Clean and Build command, the IDE runs a build script that performs the following tasks:

- Deletes any previously compiled files and other build outputs.
- Recompiles the application and builds a JAR file containing the compiled files.

> There is no difference in Netbeans 7.1, the jar will be in the ***dist*** folder :)